# How to extract block wise content from scanned pdf images?

Tags: python, tensorflow, checkbox

I need to extract block wise contents from the scanned images. 
the image is containing so many block wise contents in it. i only need to extract the text content from each block separately[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FZBP.jpg).